# NHibernate WinForms Multiple (SessionScope) Sleeping Sessions performance

Tags: sql-server, winforms, nhibernate, castle-activerecord, session-scope

I've implemented NHibernate Session per Form aproach with Castle AR (SessionScope), if i open a form, i open a (SessionScope) session and Disposes it at form close. If i open N single forms i have N db opened sleepy sessions as long as the form is opened, the question is: Sleepy sessions implies performance issues? is it wrong to have N opened sleepy sessions on db?.

Comment: session != db-connection. Sessions open connections when needed and rely on connection pooling of the provider

Comment: @Firo you're right, i agree, but i wan't to know if the session itself (without an active connection) causes performance issues, in other words, how "baddly" can be having N opened sleeping sessions around, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @manuellt, the question is:  are you having performance problems?

Comment: @Firo, thank you again for the reply, not now because we're at development phase, we want to prevent further performance problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lightweight [see](http://ayende.com/blog/4123/what-is-the-cost-of-opening-a-session)

Update:

I dont think that this will imply performance problem, maybe the servers maximum acctepted connections will be reached, but only if all sleeping sessions will perform something from time to time, otherwise thay will surely timeout.

Comment: thank you for your answer, now, client side is a lightweight process, but, when a client opens 10 forms, and the single form populates a grid, after this operation, the session remains in db opened sleeping for 10 minutes, with 5 clients working at the same time, i have 50 opened sleeping sessions, having 50 sleepy opened sessions implies a performance problem?, thank you again.